How to fix my my Ubuntu 22.00 files dpkg-query: package 'gedit' is not installed`?
I have messed up my ubuntu 22.00 main files, and now when I want to donwload a new app or update some apps I keep getting this error:
my_PC_PATH:sudo apt --fix-broken install

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  dctrl-tools
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-apt python3-dbus python3-gi
Suggested packages:
  python3-apt-dbg python-apt-doc python-dbus-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-apt python3-dbus python3-gi
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
11 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 164 kB/492 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1 914 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 python3-apt amd64 2.4.0ubuntu3 [164 kB]
Fetched 164 kB in 0s (395 kB/s)        
Selecting previously unselected package python3-apt.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'systemd' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'systemd-hwe-hwdb' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 44496 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-apt_2.4.0ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-apt (2.4.0ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-gi.
Preparing to unpack .../python3-gi_3.42.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-gi (3.42.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-dbus.
Preparing to unpack .../python3-dbus_1.2.18-3build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-dbus (1.2.18-3build1) ...
Setting up python3 (3.10.6-1~22.04) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.10...
dpkg-query: package 'gedit' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
dpkg-query: package 'gedit' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
dpkg-query: package 'rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
dpkg-query: package 'rhythmbox-plugins' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
dpkg-query: package 'ubuntu-drivers-common' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
running python post-rtupdate hooks for python3.10...
  File "/usr/share/python3/python.mk", line 20
    py_sitename = $(if $(filter $(subst python,,$(1)), 2.3 2.4 2.5),site,dist)-packages
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-gi:
 python3-gi depends on python3 (<< 3.11); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-gi depends on python3 (>= 3.10~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-gi depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-gi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of onboard-common:
 onboard-common depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package onboard-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ibus:
 ibus depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 ibus depends on python3-gi; however:
  Package python3-gi is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ibus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lsb-release:
 lsb-release depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lsb-release (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-ibus-1.0:
 python3-ibus-1.0 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-ibus-1.0 depends on python3-gi (>= 3.8); however:
  Package python3-gi is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-ibus-1.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-gi-cairo:
 python3-gi-cairo depends on python3-gi (= 3.42.1-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package python3-gi is not configured yet.
 python3-gi-cairo depends on python3 (<< 3.11); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-gi-cairo depends on python3 (>= 3.10~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-gi-cairo (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of steam-launcher:
 steam-launcher depends on python3 (>= 3.4); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package steam-launcher (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zoom:
 zoom depends on ibus; however:
  Package ibus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package zoom (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-dbus:
 python3-dbus depends on python3 (<< 3.11); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-dbus depends on python3 (>= 3.10~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-dbus depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-dbus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-cairo:amd64:
 python3-cairo:amd64 depends on python3 (<< 3.11); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-cairo:amd64 depends on python3 (>= 3.10~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-cairo:amd64 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-cairo:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-apt:
 python3-apt depends on python3 (<< 3.11); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-apt depends on python3 (>= 3.10~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-apt depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-apt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of onboard:
 onboard depends on onboard-common (<< 1.4.1-5build5.1); however:
  Package onboard-common is not configured yet.
 onboard depends on onboard-common (>= 1.4.1-5build5); however:
  Package onboard-common is not configured yet.
 onboard depends on python3-cairo; however:
  Package python3-cairo:amd64 is not configured yet.
 onboard depends on python3-dbus; however:
  Package python3-dbus is not configured yet.
 onboard depends on python3-gi-cairo; however:
  Package python3-gi-cairo is not configured yet.
 onboard depends on python3 (<< 3.11); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 onboard depends on python3 (>= 3.10~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 onboard depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package onboard (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of onboard-data:
 onboard-data depends on onboard (<< 1.4.1-5build5.1); however:
  Package onboard is not configured yet.
 onboard-data depends on onboard (>= 1.4.1-5build5); however:
  Package onboard is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package onboard-data (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 python3-gi
 onboard-common
 ibus
 lsb-release
 python3-ibus-1.0
 python3-gi-cairo
 steam-launcher
 zoom
 python3-dbus
 python3-cairo:amd64
 python3-apt
 onboard
 onboard-data
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I tried editing the the files in thie path "usr/share/python3/" but didn't work out. I tried to fix and configure some settings but I get the same error.
I tried
sudo apt install --reinstall python3 python python3-minimal --fix-brokenand
dpkg --configure -a
both return the same error shown above
But this didn't work as well.
any suggestions?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se] would be better places for questions like this.

try dpkg --configure -a but it's gonna be tough. you'd better reinstall your system
